# Get stdout and stderr of a nodejs application running in background as process

Tags: node.js, linux, process, stdout, stderr

there is an existing nodejs code on a ubuntu server running in the background. This existing code is having some issues and I want to see the console.logs of this code running.

I have found the process id of by:

```
 ps -aef | grep node
```

which gives

```
aman 20897     1  0 Sep26 ?        03:07:06 node Monitor/Broker.js
```

Can someone help with how do I find the logs/stdout/stderr for this process ?

Thanks

edit

output of `lsof -p 20897`

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using? And do you know what is running/what started the process?

Comment: Hi, its running on a ubuntu machine. I am not sure how was the process started :(

Comment: I am assuming it can be by `node Monitor/Broker.js`

Comment: You can try `lsof -p 20897` to find any open files that the process has. Alternatively, try and find a parent process (and maybe repeat the process)

I don't think there's always a way to get the logs though; if the process was started like `node server.js > /dev/null`, those logs are gone forever.

Comment: added the screenshot of output of `lsof -p 20897`, i can't figure out any files from there

Comment: Check `/home/amitbhanja/nohup.out`. That should be where the stderr and stdout are going :)

Comment: FYI, the way I knew that was to look for the values 1 and 2 in the `FD` column (they correspond to STDOUT and STDERR).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201990/discussion-between-cvg-and-mavvie).